# How can i acess results[0] in my json file function?

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, fetch

i am using a link to generating 3 different results, i am trying to access things in results[0], results[1] or results[2] in my "contactos" function but i don´t know how to do it. I thought it maybe has to be inside a For cicle, but it doesn´t work either. Can someone help me?
(every other selector works fine, but when trying to use results[] it does not work)
thanks in advance.

```js
getResultado();

function getResultado() {
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=3")
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        }).then(function(json) {
        for (var i =0; i<json.results.length; i++) {
            console.log(json.results[i]);
            objeto = json.results[i];
            document.getElementById("json").appendChild(contactos(objeto));
        }
    });
}

function contactos(info){
        let contactosElement = document.createElement("div");
        contactosElement.classList.add("contactos");
        let contactoElement = document.createElement("div");
        contactoElement.classList.add("contacto");
        contactosElement.appendChild(contactoElement);
        let imagemElement = document.createElement("div");
        imagemElement.classList.add("imagem");
        contactoElement.appendChild(imagemElement);
        let textoElement = document.createElement("div");
        textoElement.classList.add("texto");
        contactoElement.appendChild(textoElement);
        let tituloElement = document.createElement("h3");
        tituloElement.innerText = "Geral";
        textoElement.appendChild(tituloElement);
        let nomeElement = document.createElement("p");
        nomeElement.innerText = "Nome: " + info.name.first;
        textoElement.appendChild(nomeElement);
        let mailElement = document.createElement("p");
        console.log(this.results[0].email);
        
        
        
        mailElement.innerText = "Email: " + info.results[0].email;
        
        
        
        
        textoElement.appendChild(mailElement);
        let telefoneElement = document.createElement("p");
        telefoneElement.innerText = "Telefone: " + info.phone;
        textoElement.appendChild(telefoneElement);
        let fotografiaElement = document.createElement("img");
        fotografiaElement.setAttribute('src', info.picture.large);
        imagemElement.appendChild(fotografiaElement);
        return contactosElement;

}
```

Comment: There is no `this.results`; you are already passing `json.results[i]` into `contactos()` when you call it, so you need `info.email` instead. The first order of debugging is to log the stuff you're using. Insert `console.log(info)` and you will see exactly what gets passed.

Comment: Nice thanks, but the json file passes 3 emails, and I would want to access each one separately, is that possible?

Comment: you are passing each result in the array to `contactos` - so, the email would be `info.email` just like it's `info.name.first` etc ... all you've done is mess up how you get the email from `info` ... just remove `results[0]` in that line

Comment: i understand that, but the link generates 3 emails, it is corrently accessing all the 3 at onde, and i would want to access only one, is that possible?

Comment: Of course: you have a `for` loop iterating over the array; if you only want to add one, remove the loop and replace it with code for a fixed index.

Comment: i think i am not being clear, i want to make 3 contact divs, each one with one email, one name, one phone number and one photo. The link can generate up to 5000 different "users" with all their data, but i only need 3. As the link generates 3 "users" it generates 3 different names, 3 different emails, etc. What i am trying to do is load the 3 users, as it is loading now, but then, access only one, so i can put this element in a different contact div. Do you understand me?

Answer (score 0):

This is a re-write of my answer to fully accommodate what you had in mind. The central point is that you need to loop over the elements of the returned `json.results` array. I did this with `json.results.map()`, picked out the properties of interest for each user `u` and `join()`-ed them into an HTML string which I then placed in the `#json` div of your page.

```js
getResultado();

function getResultado() {
  fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=3")
  .then(r=>r.json())
  .then(json=>{
   document.getElementById("json").innerHTML=
   '<div "class=contacts">'+
   json.results.map(u=>
   `<div class="contacto">
     <div class="imagem">
      <img src="${u.picture.large}">
     </div>
     <div class="texto">
      <h3>Geral</h3>
      <p>${u.name.first} ${u.name.last}</p>
      <p>${u.phone}</p>
      <p>${u.email}</p>
     </div>
    </div>`).join('');
   });
}
```

```html
<h2>Contactos</h2>
<div id="json"></div>
```

I used the ES6 templating syntax to generate the new HTML string. This is easier to handle (and faster) than your original approach using `document.createElement()` and `element.appendChild()`.

Comment: i think i am not being clear, i want to make 3 contact divs, each one with one email, one name, one phone number and one photo. The link can generate up to 5000 different "users" with all their data, but i only need 3. As the link generates 3 "users" it generates 3 different names, 3 different emails, etc. What i am trying to do is load the 3 users, as it is loading now, but then, access only one, so i can put this element in a different contact div. Do you understand me?